# Why i can not get decimal numbers in format function?

Tags: r

```
format(1234456567.89,decimal.mark=".", big.mark = " ", big.interval = 4L)
[1] "12 3445 6568"
```

Why i can not get the number of `12 3445 6567.89`?
1.how can i get a number which is equal to   `12 3445 6567.89`?
2.how can i get a string which is equal to   `12 3445 6567.89`?

tow methods for question 1.
m1:

```
> format(1234456567.89,digits=12,decimal.mark=".", big.mark = " ", big.interval = 4L,nsmal=2L)->x
> x
[1] "12 3445 6567.89"
```

m2:

```
>formatC(1234456567.89, format="f",digits=2, decimal.mark=".", big.mark = " ", big.interval = 4L)->y
y
[1] "12 3445 6567.89"

> format(1234456567.89,digits=12,decimal.mark=".", big.interval = 4L,nsmal=2L)->z
> as.numeric(z)
[1] 1234456567.8900001049
```

how can i make `z` into a number which is `1234456567.89`?

Comment: As `?format` will tell you, this is a generic function for pretty-printing an R object. It follows that whatever it outputs will be a character string. Perhaps you could give more information on what you would like to do?

Comment: I think you probably want to define a new class which will be numeric at its core and have its own print method. If the class has its own `as` method, you can also read it in with `read.table` using 'colClasses'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe give a try of formatC?

```
> formatC(1234456567.89, format="f", decimal.mark=".", big.mark = " ", big.interval = 4L)
[1] "12 3445 6567.8900"
```

Comment: formatC(1234456567.89, format="f",digits=2, decimal.mark=".", big.mark = " ", big.interval = 4L),how can i change it into a number?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature You mean read from string in that format and turn that into a float?

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
format(1234456567.89, digits= 12, decimal.mark=".", big.mark = " ", big.interval = 4L)
```

Comment: it is a string ,how can i change it into a number?as.numeric(x) can't work.

Comment: OK, now I understand the down vote, which up to now was puzzling me. THERE ARE NO SPACES IN REAL NUMBERS.

Comment: as.numeric doesn't work because you have space in between your characters. what you want to do with numeric and how you want that- explain clearly.